# Why are bones twisting and skin weight weird when imported in unreal?

Tags: animation, unreal-engine, auto-rig-pro

we are currently trying to get an animation made in blender imported into unreal engine. But when we do the bones twist and the skin weights change:

[image]

We used autorig pro to create the skeleton and control rig in blender and everything looks fine in there. We also already have 2 other animations for the wolf made the same way that works fine.

here is a picture of a working animation:
[image]

and another picture of the failed import:
[image]

We have tried a lot of thing and looked for solutions so I hope that somebody will be familiar with this issue.

Thanks in advance!